# How do I turn off another app's audio when my app's audio starts?

Tags: ios, audio

So, I need two things:

1. When my app starts, and another app's audio is already playing, I don't want to stop that other app's audio.
2. When my app's audio starts playing (the user initiates this action) I want any other app's audio that may be currently playing to stop.

I've already accomplished #1, but need some help figuring out #2.

Here's the code I have in my App Delegate applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method that makes #1 work:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback 
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers 
                                       error:nil];
```

Comment: Untested, and barely researched: what happens if you just call the same `setCategory:withOptions:error:` method again without the `MixWithOthers` option when you want to mute the other audio? The docs say "You may also set the category or mode while the session is active."

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. Doesn't seem to do anything other than still let both apps play their audio at the same time. I don't get any errors back from the call to setCategory:error:.

Answer (score 0):

So, the key was to set the options to 0 when I actually started playing the audio in my app with a category of AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. If you just don't specify the options when you change the category, it seems to assume that you want to use the originally specified options. That's my guess anyway.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback 
                                 withOptions:0 
                                       error:nil];
```